# How to exclude the search results (Links) from a google search in Java

Tags: java

I would like to filter all website links out of a google search. If I searching for something I want to get all the website links of the sites, which google shows us.

First I want to read the full html content. Afterwards I would like to filter all the important URLs out of it. For Example -> If i put the words "buy shoes" into google -> I want to get the links like "www.amazon.in/Shoes" and so on.

If I am starting my program I get only a few urls and only google based sites like "google.de/intl/de/options/"

PS: I checked the page source with the same query ("buy+shoes") in the Chrome- and Firefox-Browser and notice that the chrome browser gives much more content than the firefox-browser. My feeling is that I get only the few website results, because the java connects like a Firefox browser, isn't it? 
How do I get all these links, which google shows up?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class findEveryUrl {
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{

    String gInput = "https://www.google.de/#q=";
    // setKeyWord asks you to enter the keyword into the console
    String fullUrl = gInput + setKeyWord();
    //fullUrl is used for the InputStream and "www." is the string, which is used for splitting
    findAllSubs( fullUrl, "www.");
    //System.out.println("given url: " + fullUrl);
}



/* 
 * @param <T> String type.
 * @param urlString has to be the full Url.
 * @param splitphrase is the String which is used for splitting. 
 * @return void
 */
static void findAllSubs( String urlString, String splitphrase )
{
    try
    {
        URL     url     = new URL( urlString );
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine ;  
        String array[];

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            inputLine += in.readLine();
            array = inputLine.split(splitphrase);
            arrayToConsol(array);

        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



/* 
 * urlQuery() asks you for the search keyword for the google query
 * @return returns the keyword, which you wrote into the console
 */
public static String setKeyWord(){
    BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter a KeyWord: ");
    //googles search engine url

    String keyWord = null;
    try {
        keyWord = console.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // shouldn't be happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return keyWord;
}

public static void arrayToConsol(String[] array){
    for (String item : array) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}

public static void searchQueryToConsole(String url) throws IOException{
    URL googleSearch = new URL(url);
    URLConnection yc = googleSearch.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple and easy solution.

http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/call-google-search-api-in-java-program/

However if you want to parse other pages with using CSS selectors to find elements JSoup its great library.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Comment: Thank you Daredesm, for your fast reply  = )